# Частичное использование Венгерской нотации

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Интересует такой вопрос, почему в примерах команды Google используется венгерская нотация только в одном случае, когда создается свойство класс и ему присваивается имя `m{VariableName}`? Кто-нибудь так ещё пишет?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще то есть [Code Style Guidelines for Contributors - Follow Field Naming Conventions](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions). И там рекомендуется использовать имя с `m` в начале, но только для не публичных и нестатических полей.

Comment: Думаю изначально следовало сделать пометку, что этот кодстайл конкретно для контрибьюторов AOSP (и то, не везде соблюдался). И вовсе не общий.

Answer (score 2):

На любителя. Лично встречал и C#-код с венгерской нотацией, да еще и с XML-комментарием, где описивался тип.

В современных IDE достаточно подвести указатель мыши к имени переменной, чтобы узнать ее тип. Но у кого-то сила привычки =)

Answer (score 0):

Советую почитать статью Джейка Уортона на эту тему:

https://jakewharton.com/just-say-no-to-hungarian-notation/

В любом случае, в частности для котлина-андроида она сейчас не используется (https://android.github.io/kotlin-guides/style.html)